# Trying to adjust my carousel, the carousel is taking up too much of the page how can i make it a small feature in the center?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

When I change the width and height to anything less than a 100% it throws off the whole code and the images cut off. I would really like it to be just center not taking up so much space.

I already resized all my images to approx. 500x500 or 500x660 as to not stretch image too much. If I change the height and width in my code it throws it all off should I change from a carousel to some kind of gallery or card? I would just like it to be in the middle not nearly the entire page.

```
<style>
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: auto;}
    .carousel-inner img{width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-success">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-1 h1">Home</span>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./index.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us!</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <p><br /><br /></p>
    <!--gallery-->
<div class="container">    
    <div id="blah" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!--indicators-->
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="7"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="8"></li>    
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="9"></li>
            <li data-target="#blah" data-slide-to="10"></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="imgs/1handle.jpg" alt="crystal handle">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/4rods.jpg" alt="a group of rods by me" >
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/blackcollage.jpg" alt="black rod" >
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/bluecollage.jpg" alt="royal blue rod">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/greencollage.jpg" alt="green rod" >
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item"> 
                <img src="imgs/redcollage.jpg" alt="red rod" >
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">     
                <img src="imgs/shinybluecoll.jpg" alt="metallic blue rod">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">     
                <img src="imgs/whiteredcoll.jpg" alt="white and red rod">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/handles.jpg" alt="assorted handles">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="imgs/customer.jpg" alt="happy customer testing the waters">
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--controls/arrows-->
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#blah" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#blah" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give image a `width: 100%;  height: auto;` it will automatically scale the image.  next adjust your carousal height and width.